# How do I pass multiple parameters to an @Input decorator function in Angular 4

Tags: angular

My Input decorator looks like this

```
    @Input()
   filler(itemName:any,itemRate:number,itemQty:number,itemDiscount:number,itemSubtotal:number)
{
 this.cart.push({name:itemName,rate:itemRate,qty:itemQty,discount:itemDiscount,subtotal:itemSubtotal});
  }
```

and the call looks like this

```
<app-bill [filler]="['Name','Rate', 'Qty', 'Discount', 'Subtotal']"></app-bill>
```

and I need to pass all those 5 values to the "filler()".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a object of that type and pass the values,

```
<app-bill [filler]="item"></app-bill>
```

where item is created from class which has all the fields

**Item.ts**

```
class Item {
    Name: string;
    Rate: number;
    Qty : number;
    Discount : number;
    SubTotal: number;
}
```

In your **`Catalog Component.ts`**

```
import { Item } from 'Item';

 export class CheckOutPageComponent{
 item : Item;
 ngOnInit() {
        item.Name = 'test';
        ,,,,,,assign rest of values here
 }
```

Comment: where should I create that class and how do I use it

Comment: In your application

Comment: @KedarUdupa it should be in parent component

Comment: I have a "Bill Component" with a "@Input" decorator and a "Catalog Component" from which I need to send data to "Bill Component", I created a class in "Catalog Component" but it didn't work.If you could be more precise it would be really helpful..?!